# How could i extract values from GET hyperlink in java?

Tags: java, regex, string, hyperlink

I have a small problem in extracting the values of the GET hyperlink.
for example:
***It has to accept the input from user***
INPUT:
https://www.something.comsignin/service?username=test&pwd=test&profile=developer&role=ELITE&key=manager

- **
- OUTPUT

**
In the above hyperlink i want values of ,
**USERNAME:test**

**PWD**:test
**PROFILE:**:developer
.....
This has to be the output.

Please help me with a code in JAVA.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe [here is the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128436/query-string-manipulation-in-java).

Comment: Some simple string operations would probably do the trick since the patter for a query string in an url would be `url?p1=v1&p2=v2...`. Just split at the appropriate characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First transform your String to `URL` and then using `getQuery()` method you can get only paramateres e.g **username=abc&password=def...** of URL and then u can split it using '**&**'

```
    String query = "https://www.something.comsignin/service?username=test&pwd=test&profile=developer&role=ELITE&key=manager";
    URL u = new URL(query);
    String param = u.getQuery();
    String paramSplit[] = param.split("&");
    System.out.println(paramSplit[0] + "\n" + paramSplit[1]); //only username and password
    for (String s : paramSplit)
        System.out.println(s);
```

**Output:**

```
username=test
pwd=test
profile=developer
role=ELITE
key=manager
```

Comment: But,I want only the values of username,pwd  so that i could use those value anywhere? thanks in advance..    @Hiru

Comment: Yes, can i store the values of username ,password,profile,role,key in any variables so that i can display the output like.<br>
Un : test 
pw : test
prfl : developer
rol  : ELITE
key : manager..
Your answers are perfect i just want to know in depth .. Thanks in advance

Comment: you can again split with "=" this will produce test,test,developer,ELITE,manager

Comment: Please tell me in detail .Don't mind im a beginner.@Hiru

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437768/adding-strings-to-an-arraylist

Comment: Im expecting your code ...@Hiru